# iOS Extension does not display image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I found this good [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l2Jn.png) how to get selected images.

I am trying to set image that I get from extension context to image view that I placed in storyboard.

this my print out code **po self.theImageView**:

```
<UIImageView: 0x7b8a1c90; frame = (240 89; 52 41); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b887fa0>> - (null)
```

and this is po **self.theImageView.image**

```
<UIImage: 0x7a6977f0>
```

So I even can see image using eye tool when debug it:
[image]

But on the screen of my simulator there is no visible image.

Comment: Did you verify that the name of the image file and the image file you're loading are the same (and case identical)?

Comment: @rebello95, not sure I understand ) I get image from extension using share button, so after I get images from context I can simple set them, If you can see I have image on my question and if I tap eye button I see selected image I want share from photos. So I just simple set it to image view as usual and eye helps me indicate if that's needed image. and that's it. but there is not image on UI so screen with my custom extension view has just my text views and buttons, but no image (

Comment: @rebello95, seems like due load items delay, after I push new controller and then pop back I see that image

Comment: I had this same problem last week. The problem was with the image. Image had white bg with black circle and my simulator couldn't process it.

Comment: @Sreejith, and how did you solve it.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander I created a new image with plain bg (Removed the white portion) and it worked.

Comment: @Sreejith in my case it was this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616701/ios-8-share-extension-show-shared-image-issue?noredirect=1#comment47379419_29616701