# iOS 8 share extension show shared image issue

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I have a problem with displaying image in my UIImageView.

So this is how I get images in ShareViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    for (NSItemProvider* itemProvider in ((NSExtensionItem*)self.extensionContext.inputItems[0]).attachments )
    {
        if([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.image"])
        {
            ++counter;

            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.image" options:nil completionHandler:
             ^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error)
             {
                 UIImage *sharedImage = nil;

                 if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
                 {
                     sharedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)item]];
                 }
                 if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
                 {
                     sharedImage = (UIImage*)item;
                 }
                 if ([(NSObject *)item isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
                 {
                     sharedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)item];
                 }

                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kNotificationDidLoadItem" object:sharedImage];
             }];
        }
    }
}
```

this is how I receive notification in DetailsViewController:

```
- (void)didLoadSharedImage:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIImage *sharedImage = [notification object];
    [self.sharedImages addObject:sharedImage];

    if (!self.theImageView.image) {

        self.theImageView.image = sharedImage;
    }
}
```

So there is no visible image after this method. I debugged it and I saw that image is there, but it's strange that I see it when I push new view controller form DetailsViewController and then pop back. Only then UIImageView seems like refresh its self.

Comment: Can you get us more details Plz?

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim, I have two UIViewControllers first which is root controller and which has extension context. From first controller I get images like in the code above. After I get an image I send it via notification to second view controller and the code with receiver also above. But the image appears with delay or sometimes does not appear. Or after I make push from second view controller and then go back, image view magically update itself

Comment: Does the secondViewController is loaded in memory when you post the notification?

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim sure, I even can track - (void)didLoadSharedImage:(NSNotification *)notification and it invokes. so in debugger I see image which I set.

Comment: Did you try to execute didLoadSharedImage into UIThread. like dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  if (!self.theImageView.image) {
        self.theImageView.image = sharedImage;
    }
});

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim great thanks it works!!! please add it as an answer

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim how did understand that?)

Comment: You say that the debugging is show the image correctly. So I guessed that it's a multithreading problem. the best practise is to ensure that you execute your notification code into UIThread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to execute didLoadSharedImage into UIThread. like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
          if (!self.theImageView.image) {
          self.theImageView.image = sharedImage; 
          } 
})
```

Good luck

Comment: `-loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler:` isn't called on the main thread, you need to dispatch onto the main thread. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSItemProvider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSItemProvider/loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler:).